# Query returning values with set column to value or null

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database containing the following:

`Products`

```
id | name              | indexname   |units
--------------------------------------------
1  |Mydełko Fa         |FA_INDEX     |szt.
2  |Ręcznik elegancki  |RECZNIK_ELEG |szt.
3  |Płyn do czyszczenia|CZYS_PLYN    |l
```

`Prices`

```
id | user_id | product_id | price
-----------------------------------
2  |NULL     |1           |21.32
3  |3        |1           |20
4  |NULL     |2           |43.21
5  |NULL     |3           |12.12
```

So as you can see there are 2 prices for product of id 1. I want to prepare a query that will return

```
id | name              | indexname   |units |price
---------------------------------------------------
1  |Mydełko Fa         |FA_INDEX     |szt.  |20
2  |Ręcznik elegancki  |RECZNIK_ELEG |szt.  |43.21
3  |Płyn do czyszczenia|CZYS_PLYN    |l     |12.12
```

So what I want is to get all rows where user_id is 3 or if such row not exists then the one where user_id is null.

I tried

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `products` p1 
JOIN `prices` p2 ON p1.id = p2.product_id 
WHERE `user_id` = 3 OR `user_id` is null
```

and some others however with no success... Could you help?

Comment: This doesn't make too much sense to me. How do you know that if there is more than one price for the product in the prices table, the right price for it will be the one corresponding to user_id = 3?

Comment: It's simple. Prices with user_id = null are default, for all users. User with id 3 has special discount.

Comment: Then I think your design is wrong. I would store the discounts apart.

Comment: So you want to select a price specific to the user if there is an entry with that user id in the `prices` table, and just the price from the record with NULL else? (If so, then next time please _ask_ that instead of having people _guess_ if that’s what you want by just showing some “example output” without further explanation [which just got you a -1 btw.].) Well, one way to do so would be to swap out the JOIN for a correlated sub-query that gets the prices for the product by id and _orders_ its results by whether or not the matched records have `user_id=3` or not, and `LIMIT` the result to 1.

Comment: (OK, question about what you want got obsoleted by comments in the meantime. Still, put it into your question right away next time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to get both at once, of course you'll get a null value if no user price exists for that user:

```
SELECT p1.*, p2.price AS null_price, p3.price AS user_price
FROM `products` p1 
JOIN `prices` p2 ON p1.id = p2.product_id AND `p2.user_id` IS NULL
LEFT JOIN `prices` p3 ON p1.id = p3.product_id AND `p3.user_id` = 3
```

Then use whatever programming language you are using to determine if the field is null, and which price to use.

Comment: You can use "ifnull(p3.price,p2.price) as user_price" to get it in one column

Comment: You could indeed, great idea

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
SELECT * FROM products p1
LEFT JOIN prices p2 ON p1.id = p2.product_id
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL OR p2.product_id IN (
  SELECT product_id FROM prices GROUP BY product_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Comment: Not at all. Adding one row to Prices table:
6| 4 | 2 | 12.21
will make your query fail...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfd50/1/0

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
JOIN prices pr ON pr.product_id = p.id
WHERE pr.user_id = 3 OR pr.user_id IS NULL;
```

Without giving the error you're receiving, it's a little hard to provide a concrete answer.